# How can I get Octave to run an executable with my input files?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, exe, octave

I want octave to run an executable for me that uses a couple of input files. I am aware of the existence of system and tried the line below:

```
 system("/home/willubuntu/acpimrepo/main.exe /home/willubuntu/_to_hesson_laptop/srcrob/TMB_Run1_Midpoints.IN GRIDS.IN")
```

I got this error: -

*** SUCCESS OPENING FILE extinction_550.nc**

   SUCCESS READING FILE extinction_550.nc
  **ALLOCATING PROGNOSTIC ARRAYS           1           1           1
 *** DONE
 nrerror: root must be bracketed for zbrent
STOP program terminated by nrerror
ans = 0

I'm trying to run a model that is executed by main.exe which uses the input files TMB_Run1_Midpoints.IN and GRIDS.IN. GRIDS.IN is located in the working directory. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 if that is relevant.

Comment: I can't see how this is related to Octave. This is an errror message Form your main.exe. You are in Ubuntu, why has main an exe extension?

Comment: Well the line of code is being run from octave? Maybe that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Would you blame bash, dash, ksh if your program doesn't work from a terminal? But let's focus on your problem. Are you able to run main.exe with TMB_Run1_Midpoints.IN and GRIDS.IN in a shell? Make sure you have the right working dir or use absolute filenames